# Chronicle Queue V3. Can Entries be lost on data block roll-over?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I have an application that writes entries to a Chronicle Queue (V3) that also retains excerpt entry index values in other (Chronicle)Maps by way of providing indexed access in the queue.  Sometimes we fail to find a given entry that we've earlier saved and I believe it maybe related to data-block roll-over.

Below is a stand-alone test program that reproduces such use-cases at small-scale.  It repeatedly writes an entry and immediately attempts to find the resulting index value up using a separate ExcerptTailer.  All is well for a while until the first data-block is used up and a second data file is assigned, then the retrieval failures start.  If the data block size is increased to avoid roll-overs, then no entries are lost.  Also using a small index data-block size, causing multiple index files to be created, doesn't cause a problem.

The test program also tries using an *ExcerptListener* running in parallel to see if the entries apparently 'lost' by the writer, are ever received by the reader thread - they're not.  Also tries to re-read the resulting queue from start until end, which reconfirms that they really are lost.

Stepping thru' the code, I see that when looking up a 'missing entry', within *AbstractVanillarExcerpt#index*, it appears to successfully locate the correct VanillaMappedBytes object from the dataCache, but determines that there is no entry and the data-offset as the *len == 0*.  In addition to the entries not being found, at some point after the problems start occurring post-roll-over, an NPE is thrown from within the *VanillaMappedFile#fileChannel* method due to it having been passed a null File path.  The code-path assumes that when resolving a entry looked up successfully in the index that a file will always have been found, but isn't in this case.

Is it possible to reliably use Chronicle Queue across data-block roll-overs, and if so, what am I doing that maybe causing the problem I'm experiencing?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import net.openhft.affinity.AffinitySupport;
import net.openhft.chronicle.Chronicle;
import net.openhft.chronicle.ChronicleQueueBuilder;
import net.openhft.chronicle.ExcerptAppender;
import net.openhft.chronicle.ExcerptCommon;
import net.openhft.chronicle.ExcerptTailer;
import net.openhft.chronicle.VanillaChronicle;

public class ChronicleTests {
    private static final int CQ_LEN = VanillaChronicle.Cycle.DAYS.length();
    private static final long CQ_ENT = VanillaChronicle.Cycle.DAYS.entries();
    private static final String ROOT_DIR = System.getProperty(ChronicleTests.class.getName() + ".ROOT_DIR",
            "C:/Temp/chronicle/");
    private static final String QDIR = System.getProperty(ChronicleTests.class.getName() + ".QDIR", "chronicleTests");
    private static final int DATA_SIZE = Integer
            .parseInt(System.getProperty(ChronicleTests.class.getName() + ".DATA_SIZE", "100000"));
    // Chunk file size of CQ index
    private static final int INDX_SIZE = Integer
            .parseInt(System.getProperty(ChronicleTests.class.getName() + ".INDX_SIZE", "10000"));
    private static final int Q_ENTRIES = Integer
            .parseInt(System.getProperty(ChronicleTests.class.getName() + ".Q_ENTRIES", "5000"));
    // Data type id
    protected static final byte FSYNC_DATA = 1;
    protected static final byte NORMAL_DATA = 0;
    protected static final byte TH_START_DATA = -1;
    protected static final byte TH_END_DATA = -2;
    protected static final byte CQ_START_DATA = -3;
    private static final long MAX_RUNTIME_MILLISECONDS = 30000;

    private static String PAYLOAD_STRING = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static byte PAYLOAD_BYTES[] = PAYLOAD_STRING.getBytes();

    private Chronicle _chronicle;
    private String _cqPath = ROOT_DIR + QDIR;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        buildCQ();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        boolean passed = true;
        Collection<Long> missingEntries = new LinkedList<Long>();
        long sent = 0;
        Thread listener = listen();
        try {
            listener.start();
            // Write entries to CQ, 
            for (int i = 0; i < Q_ENTRIES; i++) {
                long entry = writeQEntry(PAYLOAD_BYTES, (i % 100) == 0);
                sent++;
                // check each entry can be looked up
                boolean found = checkEntry(i, entry);
                if (!found)
                    missingEntries.add(entry);
                passed &= found;
            }
            // Wait awhile for the listener
            listener.join(MAX_RUNTIME_MILLISECONDS);
            if (listener.isAlive())
                listener.interrupt();
        } finally {
            if (listener.isAlive()) { // => exception raised so wait for listener
                log("Give listener a chance....");
                sleep(MAX_RUNTIME_MILLISECONDS);
                listener.interrupt();
            }
            log("Sent: " + sent + " Received: " + _receivedEntries.size());
            // Look for missing entries in receivedEntries 
            missingEntries.forEach(me -> checkMissingEntry(me));
            log("All passed? " + passed);
            // Try to find missing entries by searching from the start...
            searchFromStartFor(missingEntries);
            _chronicle.close();
            _chronicle = null;
            // Re-initialise CQ and look for missing entries again...
            log("Re-initialise");
            init();
            searchFromStartFor(missingEntries);
        }
    }

    private void buildCQ() {
        try {
            // build chronicle queue
            _chronicle = ChronicleQueueBuilder.vanilla(_cqPath).cycleLength(CQ_LEN).entriesPerCycle(CQ_ENT)
                    .indexBlockSize(INDX_SIZE).dataBlockSize(DATA_SIZE).build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new InitializationException("Failed to initialize Active Trade Store.", e);
        }
    }

    private long writeQEntry(byte dataArray[], boolean fsync) throws IOException {
        ExcerptAppender appender = _chronicle.createAppender();
        return writeData(appender, dataArray, fsync);
    }

    private boolean checkEntry(int seqNo, long entry) throws IOException {
        ExcerptTailer tailer = _chronicle.createTailer();
        if (!tailer.index(entry)) {
            log("SeqNo: " + seqNo + " for entry + " + entry + " not found");
            return false;
        }
        boolean isMarker = isMarker(tailer);
        boolean isFsyncData = isFsyncData(tailer);
        boolean isNormalData = isNormalData(tailer);
        String type = isMarker ? "MARKER" : isFsyncData ? "FSYNC" : isNormalData ? "NORMALDATA" : "UNKNOWN";
        log("Entry: " + entry + "(" + seqNo + ") is " + type);
        return true;
    }

    private void log(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    private void searchFromStartFor(Collection<Long> missingEntries) throws IOException {
        Set<Long> foundEntries = new HashSet<Long>(Q_ENTRIES);
        ExcerptTailer tailer = _chronicle.createTailer();
        tailer.toStart();
        while (tailer.nextIndex())
            foundEntries.add(tailer.index());
        Iterator<Long> iter = missingEntries.iterator();
        long foundCount = 0;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            long me = iter.next();
            if (foundEntries.contains(me)) {
                log("Found missing entry: " + me);
                foundCount++;
            }
        }
        log("searchFromStartFor Found: " + foundCount + " of: " + missingEntries.size() + " missing entries");
    }

    private void checkMissingEntry(long missingEntry) {
        if (_receivedEntries.contains(missingEntry))
            log("Received missing entry:" + missingEntry);
    }

    Set<Long> _receivedEntries = new HashSet<Long>(Q_ENTRIES);

    private Thread listen() {
        Thread returnVal = new Thread("Listener") {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    int receivedCount = 0;
                    ExcerptTailer tailer = _chronicle.createTailer();
                    tailer.toStart();
                    while (receivedCount < Q_ENTRIES) {
                        if (tailer.nextIndex()) {
                            _receivedEntries.add(tailer.index());
                        } else {
                            ChronicleTests.this.sleep(1);
                        }
                    }
                    log("listener complete");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log("Interupted before receiving all entries");
                }
            }
        };
        return returnVal;
    }

    private void sleep(long interval) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // No action required
        }
    }

    protected static final int THREAD_ID_LEN = Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    protected static final int DATA_TYPE_LEN = Byte.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    protected static final int TIMESTAMP_LEN = Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    protected static final int CRC_LEN = Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;

    protected static long writeData(ExcerptAppender appender, byte dataArray[],
            boolean fsync) {
        appender.startExcerpt(DATA_TYPE_LEN + THREAD_ID_LEN + dataArray.length
                + CRC_LEN);
        appender.nextSynchronous(fsync);
        if (fsync) {
            appender.writeByte(FSYNC_DATA);
        } else {
            appender.writeByte(NORMAL_DATA);
        }
        appender.writeInt(AffinitySupport.getThreadId());
        appender.write(dataArray);
        appender.writeLong(CRCCalculator.calcDataAreaCRC(appender));
        appender.finish();
        return appender.lastWrittenIndex();
    }

    protected static boolean isMarker(ExcerptCommon excerpt) {
        if (isCqStartMarker(excerpt) || isStartMarker(excerpt) || isEndMarker(excerpt)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected static boolean isCqStartMarker(ExcerptCommon excerpt) {
        return isDataTypeMatched(excerpt, CQ_START_DATA);
    }

    protected static boolean isStartMarker(ExcerptCommon excerpt) {
        return isDataTypeMatched(excerpt, TH_START_DATA);
    }

    protected static boolean isEndMarker(ExcerptCommon excerpt) {
        return isDataTypeMatched(excerpt, TH_END_DATA);
    }

    protected static boolean isData(ExcerptTailer tailer, long index) {
        if (!tailer.index(index)) {
            return false;
        }
        return isData(tailer);
    }

    private static void movePosition(ExcerptCommon excerpt, long position) {
        if (excerpt.position() != position)
            excerpt.position(position);
    }

    private static void moveToFsyncFlagPos(ExcerptCommon excerpt) {
        movePosition(excerpt, 0);
    }

    private static boolean isDataTypeMatched(ExcerptCommon excerpt, byte type) {
        moveToFsyncFlagPos(excerpt);
        byte b = excerpt.readByte();
        if (b == type) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected static boolean isNormalData(ExcerptCommon excerpt) {
        return isDataTypeMatched(excerpt, NORMAL_DATA);
    }

    protected static boolean isFsyncData(ExcerptCommon excerpt) {
        return isDataTypeMatched(excerpt, FSYNC_DATA);
    }

    /**
     * Check if this entry is Data
     * 
     * @param excerpt
     * @return true if the entry is data
     */
    protected static boolean isData(ExcerptCommon excerpt) {
        if (isNormalData(excerpt) || isFsyncData(excerpt)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem only occurs when initialising the data-block size with a value that is **not a power of two**.  The built-in configurations on `IndexedChronicleQueueBuilder` (`small()`, `medium()`, `large()`) take care to initialise using powers of two which provided the clue as to the appropriate usage.

Notwithstanding the above response regarding support, which I totally appreciate, it would be useful if a knowledgeable Chronicle user could confirm that the integrity of Chronicle Queue depends on using a data-block size of a power of two.

Comment: The block size should be a power of two, and there should be code to enforce this. In v4, the size is rounded up to the next power of 2.